# Change the color of selectedListItem to red in C#

Tags: c#, html

I have created a drop down in a C# controller and using a @Html.DropDownListFor to display it.

The problem is I want to display the selected value in red color. It happens when user go to modify page to change his/her selection and drop down then should show what he previously selected in red color.

I have already created the drop down and now user can see the previously selected value. I just don't know how to change the color in c# code while I am doing this

```
if (financierEntity.EntityId == selectedFinancierEntityId)
{
    SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = financierEntity.NodeName,
        Value = financierEntity.EntityId.ToString(),
        Selected = true,
       // need to change the text in red color ?
    };

}
```

Here is my code in view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedFinancier, Model.FinancierEntities)
```

Comment: You'll need to do this using CSS

Comment: thanks but can you please explain in detail how ?

Comment: If the selected item is changed, which item is supposed to be red? The previously selected item or the new item?

Comment: previous selected item is supposed to remain red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the code, but something on these lines should work:

```
<select name="SelectedFinancier">
    @foreach (var item in Model.FinancierEntities)
    {
        <option value="@item.Value"
            @(item.Selected ? "selected" : "")
            style="color: red">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```